# Phoenix HTML: specific select options disabled

Tags: html, forms, web, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking for a way to make **specific** dropdown-options *disabled*, and others *selectable*/*non-disabled*.

I have looked at [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4), but there seems to be only an option to disable the whole select-thing, not the specific options.

I would like to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: I just read the source and I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with `Phoenix.HTML.Form.select/4` as the list of attributes for `<option>` is hardcoded to only `value` and `selected`. Looks like you'll have to roll your own wrapper using `content_tag` for now.

Comment: It depends also how do you want to disable this options - is simple JS fine or you need block it on server side? If on server side, write nice wrapper as @Dogbert wrote and consider creating pull request to Phoenix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jose Valim! This issue has been fixed.

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/issues/145#event-949081277